# Separate Servers for TFTP and DHCP for PXE Boot

Tags: pxe-boot, dnsmasq, tftp

This seems like it should be simple, but I can't find any actual information: Is it possible to have two separate servers, one running dnsmasq doing DHCP while the TFTP (or HTTP) server is running on a separate machine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the dnsmasq example config

```
# An example of dhcp-boot with an external TFTP server: the name and IP
# address of the server are given after the filename.
# Can fail with old PXE ROMS. Overridden by --pxe-service.
#dhcp-boot=/var/ftpd/pxelinux.0,boothost,192.168.0.3

# If there are multiple external tftp servers having a same name
# (using /etc/hosts) then that name can be specified as the
# tftp_servername (the third option to dhcp-boot) and in that
# case dnsmasq resolves this name and returns the resultant IP
# addresses in round robin fasion. This facility can be used to
# load balance the tftp load among a set of servers.
#dhcp-boot=/var/ftpd/pxelinux.0,boothost,tftp_server_name
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't actually tried anything yet, I wanted to verify it was possible. Upvoted and accepted.